# Hive not storing Warehouse in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have downloaded hive installation on my local system and copied hive-site.xml into Spark conf directory. I tried to create a managed table in Hive context using spark shell.

I have put following property in hive-site.xml (present in spark's conf directory):

```
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
```

Also I have put HADOOP_HOME in spark-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/conf
```

As per Hive documentation, the hive warehouse should get stored in HDFS, but the warehouse is getting stored in local drive (/user/hive/warehouse).
Please help me out in understanding why Hive is not storing warehouse directory in HDFS.

Comment: Could you paste hte value of the property `fs.defaultFS` found in the file `/opt/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please define your Spark dependencies using 2.0.2

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2"
```

You can then use `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` or `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to set the Spark warehouse and point to HDFS where the other Hive tables live.